# Patch management for Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, packages

Are there any patch managers or tools that could

1. centrally manage multiple Raspberry/Raspbian OS?
2. patch kernel/os/packages/application, selectively or whole.
3. Agents if any will need to be able to run on ARM processors.
4. managed repository locally, as internet access can be quite restrictive.

note: testing with spacewalk, manage to patch packages, not at kernel (pls let me know if anybody manage this),moving on with any recommendation.

Thanks.
vincent.

Comment: What kind of patching? Could you give some examples? If it's just a case of syncing files you could use rsync. Also, have you seen this previous question: http://serverfault.com/questions/387986/how-do-you-approach-centralised-patch-management-for-linux

Comment: If its managing few raspberry pi's on a network and set rules/apply patches on systems tied to a network you can look at `PiNet`.

Comment: hi Jodes, for patching, i am looking at kernel, os level patches, down to application level patches, the issue most patch managers is ARM support, which i believe is not supported by puppet or chef.

Comment: Please edit details into the question, not comments.  Have you checked what "you believe" about puppet and chef?  I don't use either of them but I believe someone I know uses the former on Raspbian, and a quick check of `apt search puppet` confirms it is available (and so is `chef`).

Comment: Try Saltstack if you want a complicated solution. ClusterSSH is an alternative too

Comment: Hi Orphans, thanks for the info. looking into them.